# World Map of Naruto Universe

Tags: naruto

The World map in Naruto seems to be quite small as it is easily traversable via land and the map is relatively compact ad shown in the Anime at many instances. Was there ever shown what lies beyond the sea surrounding the Great Ninja Villages.

I know it's not a Flat Earth World as in the Last Naruto Shippuden Movie we see the moon and Earth from.

Considering the scaling between the actual Earth and the fictional Earth is same is there any reference to other lands except the Major villages and the minor villages in betwen which are all apparently connected by land.

I'm referring to this map-
https://images.app.goo.gl/24gTcKJBZwtL4Ajm9

Comment: There hasn't been an official statement about what surrounds the known shinobi geography (http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-a5BntphQYgk/WCVvo4oShYI/AAAAAAACZD0/56zAgtcWdIY08nFDvHAxu8bjHtsvxrVpgCHM/s16000/0009-015.png). So the answer is no. It has not been shown.

Comment: I'll just put this here because I still don't have a clue on how to answer this: the Earth shown [in the *The Last* movie](https://blog.goo.ne.jp/papikosachimama/e/f1880eb03012a601faace08606fae904), and [in *Ultimate Ninja STORM 4* game](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1246734722). Whether it's a canon or not, I guess it's possible to infer the map from the game texture (read: hack the game), but that's a different question...

Comment: @AkiTanaka yeah but that wouldn't be actual evidence as it is not meant to be used that way to draw conclusions. Only evidence from interviews or other handbooks can be definitive in this case

Comment: I was going to edit the question to add markup code and an attribution to the work, but a reverse image search suggests that [this is an unofficial map](https://www.deviantart.com/uchidakarasu/art/naruto-map-with-ocean-297183857), in which case I think it is unsuitable to use as the basis of a question regarding the actual series, due to potential inaccuracy. Do you know if it is from an official source, or is what I found likely to be it?

Comment: I know that it resembles closely the official map as shown in the anime however I didn't check it's authenticity. I'll be happy if you can provide a better source

Comment: @Tonepoet I've added the map present on the Fandom

Comment: There's only one instance of the earth being shown in almost entirety. That's in 'The Last' movie. There's no other interviews or discussions from Kishimoto, about this.

Comment: @EroSɘnnin I couldn't find anything either that's why I asked this question

Answer (score -1):

You know how they explained in Shippuden thaat they discovered Chakra and stuff and figured out how to use it to their benefit? There are five ninja villages. Konoha, Sunagakure, Kirigakure, Kumogakure, Iwagakure. They are all conviniently placed close to eachother by the lands they are in. There maye be many other villages around them like the Iron village or whatever its called with the samurai that look like stormtroopers. Villages that do not wish to be associated with the ninja world, so they cut themselves off from it completely and are never mentioned in Naruto because they do not have any purpose besides being in the world itself.Now, because this website doesn't like guessing, I'll call this an educated guess, seeing as it is backed up by some evidence, at least. I hope that was a good answer, and actually I've been thinking about that too. Like, what other countries and continents are there besides the land of the fire and et cetera?

Comment: Seems like a nice theory but their villages were pretty much entangled according to the anime

Comment: But how could there possibly be only those lands in the entire world? There must be others apart from the main ninja lands that dont have ninjutsu or any knowledge of jutsu.

Comment: yeah I think that's a wonderful theory but I'm looking for more f something which has some backing like an interview or something

Comment: A clear fact speaking against this idea is that there are a lot of bad guys in the ninja world which operate out of e.g. greed. If there would be any countries without Ninja in it, they would just go there and build their own dictatorship. Which would prbably again entangle the ninja nations as they have to capture the Nukenins. This would again make them knowing about the situation which is why they would reach out for the Power the Chakra promises. It is only possible to have small non-ninja countries in between the five nations, as they are protected by the nations.

Comment: Protected either as a vassal or because of conflicting interests of several powers.